# JQuery - on-Function

Tags: jquery

can this code affect other submit buttons which are not in the  with the id="form_data_voting" ? I assume not, right? And the 3rd line does just affect the code of the  with the id #form_data_voting as well, right?

```
jQuery('body').on('submit', '#form_data_voting', function() {

var formContents = jQuery(this).serializeArray();           
var formSource = jQuery(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr("alt");
```

I'm facing problems with two plugins in wordpress which are both activated and the submit button of the other plugin does not work correctly...

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out... the reason was my JQuery 1.9.1 which i included with this code:

//INCLUDES
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
 $myStyleFile =  plugins_url( 'js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js', __FILE__ ) ;
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_script',$myStyleFile,false,'1.0');
});

But how can i check whether JQuery has already been included through other plugins...?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually an event handler for the form being submitted, as opposed to the button being clicked, so it will handle programmatic submits as well as people pressing enter on inputs that trigger submit.

And yes, the third line of code will only find the submit element(s) within the form specified.

Answer (score 0):

You could force the submit, but it's kinda strange.

```
$('.your-other-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#form_data_voting').submit();
});
```

It will run your previous code.

You might even get some more external forms within the submit :

```
var otherFormContents = jQuery('#yourOtherForm').serializeArray();
```

I agree with [@Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15367951/1145578) btw.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this applies only on the id=#form_data_voting. (including the third line)

In the mean time, this is not complete code, the `{` has to be closed.

if it was like this

```
jQuery('body').on('submit', '#form_data_voting', function() {

  var formContents = jQuery(this).serializeArray();           
  var formSource = jQuery(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr("alt");
}
```

Then this should work as expected. and yes to your questions.